# Discord oAuth2: How do I get the authentification header working

Tags: node.js, oauth, discord, node-fetch

**What I am trying/wanting it to do:** I am trying to make it log the info of a user after authorization

**What happens:** It says `{ message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0 }` whenever I fetch the users info, even though I put the authorization headers

**The code**:

```js
app.get('/oauth', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.code) {
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

fetch('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${req.query.code}`,
  }
})
.then(result => result.json())
.then(info => console.log(info))
res.send('CODE: ' + req.query.code)
  } else {
  res.send('<script>window.location.assign("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=880520534125838356&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwidgets.fireyjs.repl.co%2Foauth&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds.join%20messages.read")</script>')
  }
});
```

Comment: where are you getting req.query.code?  is it an access token? please edit your question and include the code you are using to get the access token.

Comment: You need to exchange the exchange code after OAuth Authentication on Discord before you receive the access token (bearer) according to the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant)

Comment: @DaImTo I have edited the code for you

Comment: I think you should consult the documentation that is not how to request an access token https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#a-quick-example